# Need assistance with understanding .each() and issue with duplicate in Ajax GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax code as below :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  EmployeeStates("Available", 1, 15);
});
function EmployeeStates(state, pageNumber, pageSize) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://localhost:58102/api/EmployeeState?state=" + state + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber + "&pageSize=" + pageSize,
    //data: JSON.stringify({ "state": state,"pageNumber":pageNumber,"pageSize":pageSize }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

      $.each(data, function (index, emp) {
        $("#ReservationDesignation").append(emp.employee.designation.designationName);
      });


    },
    fail: function (error) {
      Console.Log(error);
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

While assigning the Designation name (emp.employee.designation.designationName) to #ReservationDesignation, I am getting a duplicate.
ie, ArchitectArchitect. The actual result should be Architect.

I am not familiar with .each() function.

Can anyone help me to remove the duplicate from the result?

Thank You.

Comment: What returns your url?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you.

Comment: Yes Sjeiti, its for removing duplicates. What i want to know is how to prevent duplicates from getting created in the first place

Comment: You would remove the duplicates like how @Sjeiti linked to THEN you would append them to DOM.

Comment: The issue is your backend then, nothing wrong with the Javascript. What are you calling to? Somekind of REST framework I presume. You can always filter out duplicates in the frontend, but it's way better to fix it in the backend of course. ... -edit- oh wait... as @Darkrum indicated: there is something wrong with your Javascript but it's a whole other issue: never add stuff to DOM in a loop, and don't do queries inside the loop that you can do outside. Search for: documentFragment jquery